# Alien Invasion score is in the top left corner instead in the top right corner

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I just finished Python's game "Alien Invasion", but I have one very annoying problem, namely I can't fix the position of the score. It should be in the top right corner, but in my case is showing in the top left corner. My code is the same as in the book, even I tried copy-pasting the code from the internet but the result it's the same.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRFsw.jpg)

Here is the code for the score:

```py
    def prep_score(self):
        """Turn the score into a randered image."""
        rounded_score = round(self.stats.score, -1)
        score_str = "{:,}".format(rounded_score)
        self.score_image = self.font.render(score_str, True, self.text_color, self.settings.bg_color)

        # Display the score at the top right of the screen.
        self.score_rect = self.score_image.get_rect()
        self.score_rect.right = self.screen_rect.right - 20
        self.score_rect.top = 20
```

Comment: How do you draw the score? Do you even use `score_rect` when you `blit` the score? Do you use a `pygame.sprite.Sprite`?

Comment: Your question as written lacks sufficient detail to answer your question.  Please edit your question to show how you generate the display and how you define the value ```self.screen_rect.right```

Comment: Yes I do. The high score and the level are placed correctly, only the score causing problems.

    def show_score(self):
        """Draw scores and the level to the screen."""
        self.screen.blit(self.score_image, self.screen_rect)
        self.screen.blit(self.high_score_image, 
  self.high_score_rect)
        self.screen.blit(self.level_image, self.level_rect)
        self.ships.draw(self.screen)

Comment: `high_score_rect` != `score_rect`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on this code I think the score should appear at the top right corner of the screen. I can think of two things:

1. Check if "self.score_rect" is modified after you have set it!
2. Make sure that the "prep_score()" method is called at the appropriate time and in the correct order within your program.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much!! I've wound the problem. It was in self.screen.blit(). Instead of self.score_rect it was self.screen_rect